# Python requests add extra headers to HTTP GET

Tags: python, python-2.7, http-headers, python-requests

I am using python 2.7 requests module.

I made this HTTP GET with the custom header below;

```
header ={
            "projectName": "zhikovapp",
            "Authorization": "Bearer HZCdsf="
        }
response = requests.get(bl_url, headers = header)
```

The server returns a response that was not valid. On closer examination of the header that was sent, I discovered python requests module added some extra headers.

```
{
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
'projectName': 'zhikovapp',
'Accept': '*/*', 
'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.11.1', 
'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
'Authorization': 'Bearer HZCdsf='
}
```

The extra headers are `Accept-Encoding`, `Accept`, `Connection`, `User-Agent`. Is this a bug in python requests module? I am using requests ver 2.11.1

How can I remove these extra headers added by python requests module?

Comment: This is not a bug. HTTP-Requests normally have some standard headers, that are always send. Don't remove them.

Comment: Why is the response not valid? Does it have anything to do with invalid headers?

Comment: Daniel, I wrote similar code using node.js. These extra headers were not present and the server responded without error for the node.js code.

Comment: How do you have a `'` before `"Authorization"`?

Comment: It is a typo error. You are observant. I have made the corrections in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a prepared request.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests

then you can delete the headers manually

```
del prepped.headers['Content-Type']
```